# Copy or migrate own question?

Tags: discussion, migration

I have asked two questions at SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634525/is-there-a-timeout-for-a-query-over-database-link) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646048/why-does-dbms-scheduler-max-run-duration-not-raise-event-job-over-max-dur)), but out of the low response rate I guess they would better be placed at https://dba.stackexchange.com/ as well(?).

So question is: shall I try to migrate these questions or is it ok/acceptable to simply ask them at dba as well? In my feeling they are ok at both sites (borderline development / DBA issue).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please don't post the same question on both sites. You can flag the questions to have them migrated, instead of waiting for 4 others to feel the same way as you through voting to close, but I already have. You'll just need to wait, but you will get notification once they've been migrated.

Comment: I see, thanks. I guess I will wait a few days on SO, maybe someone still gets interested into answering. Then I'll vote/flag them to be closed & migrated.

Comment: @GWu You don't usually have to wait that long; case in point, these two questions I've flagged have already been migrated. Whether that will get you better answers might be a different story, but I agree that they are a better fit for dba.se.